# SWF: Redirect to local HTML

Tags: html, flash, redirect

getUrl() works fine for https urls, but doesn't seem to work with relative urls  (for example, `getUrl("../foo.html", "_blank");` does not work). Is there any way to redirect in SWF using relative urls?

In case it matters, this would be for an offline webpage running locally.

EDIT: As SWF does not seem to have suitable redirect capabilities, I have resolved to using JavaScript for the redirect.

Comment: There's a lot of restrictions about running SWF from local filesystem. Probably it is the most restricted setup you could ever find, because SWF is a document **and** a program thus a potential security threat. There are two things you might try. 1) Add your SWF location to trusted locations with Global Adobe Flash Security Settings. 2) Make a proxy javascript function and call it, it is possible that javascript is allowed to change **document.location.href** in such a manner.

Comment: That's a shame. Yeah, I think using Javascript for the redirect will probably be my best bet. Thanks for the response!